# How to process line-break <br> in react/javascript and convert it to html

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

If I have a javascript variable, for example in react:

```
{variable}
```

And if I print it I get:

```
one<br><br>None
```

How can I change the `<br><br>` that comes from the database for the html breakline and get as result:

```
one

None
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do this with the function `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`.

https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: variable}} />;
```

Then HTML codes will be rendered as such.

Answer (score 0):

I think when you receive string 
 from database, it is string and not html element and react cannot display it as html element. You can use this [react-html-parser](https://github.com/wrakky/react-html-parser#readme) to convert such html templates received from database to display as html element.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactHtmlParser, { processNodes, convertNodeToElement, htmlparser2 } from 'react-html-parser';

const StringToHtml = () => {
// retrieves variable here
  return (
    return <div>{ ReactHtmlParser(variable) }</div>;
  );
}
export default StringToHtml;
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, React escapes the HTML to prevent XSS (Cross-site scripting). If you really want to render HTML, you can use the [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml) property:

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: variable}} />
```

Or you can use any node package which parse html strings.